# Publish appsettings.production.json onto azure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I have an asp.net core 1.0.0 app in VS 2015 Update 3 with two appsettings-- appsettings.Development.json and appsettings.Production.json.  I'm trying to use VS to publish my app into Azure and I need for it to use the configuration in appsettings.Production.json.  However I can't seem to get it working.  It doesn't even seem to use the development json-- just the base appsettings.json which doesn't have anything.

So how do I get the VS publishing to work in Azure using the appsettings.Production.json configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the following blog post:

http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/03/21/configure-aspnetcore.html

It talks about using environment specific configurations. It appears that the concepts of transforms was not brought over yet.

Comment: Thanks.  I think everything is already set up for Core with the various application settings that can be done (development, production, staging, etc).  For testing it's simple as changing the launch settings.  However it's the publishing-- particularly to azure-- that I would like to get solved.  Wish there was an option in the publish wizard which would allow one to select which environment based on the # of app settings existing in the project.

Comment: If you use the following lines from the article I linked:
`.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)`
Then, you can use an Azure App Service setting to override the environment name. Within the App Settings for the App Service, add a new setting called `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and set it to whatever environment it should grab the settings from.

Comment: I've tried that before.  The problem is that the appsettings.Production.json doesn't even get pushed onto the Azure server... just appsettings.json.  So even setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT on Azure doesn't do any good if it can't find any additional files.

Comment: In your project.json file, are the environment specific json files listed under publishOptions --> include?

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In `project.json`, ensure that `publishOptions/include` contains `appsettings.Production.json`.

Comment: Justin Patten suggested this check in a comment on a different answer. It's worthy of its own answer for a more direct solution.